# Wooden storm window repair and painting

Tags: repair, windows, painting

I have wooden storm windows circa 1943 that are still in good condition. I've had the panes re-puttied, and now need to do painting.  A few of the storms have some minor wood damage as shown in the pictures below:

The wood is not rotted, just missing.  Some have corners missing, (first picture) and there are some visible open joints (second picture).

**Questions:**

1. What is the best way to repair this sort of damage?
2. I will prime with an oil based primer. When I paint, do I slightly overlap the paint onto the glass (a painter once said this is what I should do) or tape the glass up to the putty when painting?

[image]
[image]

Comment: "and now need to do painting"... I would say that you "now need to do stripping and sanding", then priming and painting.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Well, yes. :) I was including that in the painting, although I doubt that I'll completely strip all the old paint off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've reglazed, there aren't many options for re-clamping the corners, so... do repairs with a two part wood filler ("bondo" in North America).

Regarding the primer, try to find out if it was latex or oil based putty (tip: if it dried fast, it was latex; if it can still be imprinted with your thumb after 3 weeks, it's oil), and match your primer to that. Your painter is correct -- you should overlap a 16th onto the glass.